# why is this a mem leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

got this warning of a mem leak in the following...

any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self newOrReusableCell];


    cell.textLabel.text = [_evaluationArray objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}
```

thanks

EDIT: here s the warning:
... Object allocated on line 128 and stored into 'cell' is returned from a method whose name ('tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:') does not contain 'copy' or otherwise starts with 'new' or 'alloc'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa (object leaked)

Comment: What compiler do you use?? That's the best compiler warning I've ever seen :O

Comment: @Wevah I always use Clang but I've never seen such a warning.

Comment: @Radek S: Do you use the static analyzer? (Whoops: Not the compiler itself.)

Answer (score 0):

ah! forget it! found the answer.. is the way i named my cell...

Comment: The issue is that the method starts with `new`, which in standard Obj-C naming conventions means the method returns a retained object.